# Each person gets their top, or second choice of activity over a period of 6 slots

Tags: classification, optimization, data-wrangling

We are running a camp for 130 children, and on 3 days they can pick different activities to do. One activities for slot 1 (45min), the other for slot 2 (another 45min), enabling them to do 6 activities all together. Some activities have space for 5 children for a slot (crate stacking), while others have room for 40 children (swimming pool).
I would like them to rate the activities in order of preferences and to enable them to have their top pick or second top pick during those 3 days.
Is there a program or tool (happy to pay for it) that would enable us to do this?

Comment: Interesting problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're suggesting could be solved using the [Gale-Shapley algorithm](https://towardsdatascience.com/gale-shapley-algorithm-simply-explained-caa344e643c2). I sadly haven't found a tool out there that's ready to use.

Otherwise, you could try to solve it using integer programming. This might be the easiest way to explcitly define and use your constraints (schedule, max number of kids). And your objective function to minimize could be how "far" from their choices the kids are. With this number of constraints and variables, you could probably use the free solver provided by Gurobi.

Below, you can find a simple (and not tested) example of what this could look like

```py
from gurobipy import Model, GRB

def schedule_activities(children, activities, preferences, capacities):
    # Create a new model
    m = Model("activity_scheduling")

    # Number of slots
    slots_per_day = 2
    days = 3
    total_slots = slots_per_day * days

    # Variables: x[child,activity,slot] = 1 if child is assigned to activity in slot
    x = m.addVars(children, activities, range(total_slots), vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")

    # Constraint: Each child can be assigned to only 1 activity per slot
    for child in children:
        for slot in range(total_slots):
            m.addConstr(sum(x[child, activity, slot] for activity in activities) == 1, f"one_activity_per_slot_{child}_{slot}")

    # Constraint: Activities have limited capacities
    for activity in activities:
        for slot in range(total_slots):
            m.addConstr(sum(x[child, activity, slot] for child in children) <= capacities[activity], f"capacity_{activity}_{slot}")

    # Objective: Maximize preferences
    # Assuming preferences[child][activity] gives a preference score (higher is better)
    m.setObjective(sum(x[child, activity, slot] * preferences[child][activity] for child in children for activity in activities for slot in range(total_slots)), GRB.MAXIMIZE)

    # Optimize model
    m.optimize()

    # Extract the schedule
    schedule = {(child, slot): activity for child in children for activity in activities for slot in range(total_slots) if x[child, activity, slot].X > 0.5}

    return schedule

# Example data
children = ['Child1', 'Child2', 'Child3']  # Simplified list of children
activities = ['Swimming', 'Crate Stacking']  # Simplified list of activities
preferences = {
    'Child1': {'Swimming': 10, 'Crate Stacking': 5},
    'Child2': {'Swimming': 8, 'Crate Stacking': 9},
    'Child3': {'Swimming': 7, 'Crate Stacking': 6}
}
capacities = {'Swimming': 40, 'Crate Stacking': 5}

# Solve
schedule = schedule_activities(children, activities, preferences, capacities)
for key, value in schedule.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this advice. Will have a proper look over it in the next few weeks and see what can be done. Sad that there does not seem to be a tool or programme out there that would do it for you as it seems very much needed.